# How do I post a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Pretty new to ASP.NET and programming.  I have two models, two API controllers, two repositories.  How do I post the data to the second model while attaching it to the first (I'm guessing by ID.)  Do I possibly need a View Model?  Also reading a little about unit of work.  Maybe neither are necessary?  Below is some code.  Thanks!

Record.cs

```
namespace Train.Models {
public class Record {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cars> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

}

Cars.cs

```
namespace Train.Models {
public class Cars {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EmptyOrLoaded { get; set; }
    public string CarType { get; set; }
    //Hopper, flatbed, tank, gondola, etc.
    public string ShippedBy { get; set; }
    //UP(Union Pacific) or BNSF
    public string RailcarNumber { get; set; }
    //public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string RecordId { get; set; }
    public virtual Record Record { get; set; }

}
```

}

Record Repository

```
       public void SaveRecord(Record recordToSave) {

        if (recordToSave.Id == 0) {
            recordToSave.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            _db.Record.Add(recordToSave);
            _db.SaveChanges();

        } else {
            var original = this._db.Record.Find(recordToSave.Id);
            original.Quantity = recordToSave.Quantity;
            original.IsActive = true;

            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

EFRepository (Cars)

```
     public void SaveCar(Cars carToSave) {
        if (carToSave.Id == 0) {
            _db.Cars.Add(carToSave);
            _db.SaveChanges();

        } else {
            var original = this.Find(carToSave.Id);
            original.EmptyOrLoaded = carToSave.EmptyOrLoaded;
            original.CarType = carToSave.CarType;
            original.ShippedBy = carToSave.ShippedBy;
            original.RailcarNumber = carToSave.RailcarNumber;
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does your EF model specify the foreign key relationship?

Comment: No it doesn't.  How do I do that?

Comment: Are you doing model first or code first?

Comment: Start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712907(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Thanks so much!  Don't I also need to reference something in my Save method in my repository?  It isn't going to automatically save the record ID is it?

Comment: If you have your entities properly attached and the ID is properly setup as the primary key, EF should do all the heavy lifting for you. Give it a shot. let us know how it goes.

Comment: Last question before I try.  Do I need:    public Standard()
    {
        StudentsList = new List<Student>();
    }    I haven't seen that before and I dont have a definition for StudentsList (CarsList)

Comment: The Link I provided is just a generic tutorial for Entity Framework, you will need to modify it to serve your own purpose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127598/discussion-between-scottvmeyers-and-oxymoron).